# How to connect to http with authentication required in android?

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection

I have a problem in accessing http with a authentication required in android. I already tried the HttpUrlConnection like the code below: But I'm still getting the error 401 UNAUTHORIZED

```
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString((_username+":"+_password).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Host", "crmweb.com.ph");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", "");
        connection.connect();
```

Here is the image i want to put in code in android: [image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: it give me a response of error 401 which is unauthorized I'd check the username and password I'm putting on requestProperty of HttpUrlConnection but it still doesn't work. I think I'm doing the wrong way of connecting to that authentication required image.

Comment: You should put more effort in describing what you've done, what your code is and what happens at which line of the code you're showing us. This way, nobody can help you.